# Flutter for iOS - CRASH right after installing SDK

Tags: ios, flutter

Attempting to install the Flutter SDK on an old iMac, right after downloading and unzipping the SDK and successfully setting up the PATH for the terminal, flutter will not open.

When attempting to use flutter doctor, the system always CRASHES, indicating the following error report:

***===== CRASH =====
version=2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297 (Thu Nov 8 23:00:07 2018 +0100) on "macos_x64"
si_signo=Illegal instruction: 4(4), si_code=1, si_addr=0x10ae84fa9***

***===== CRASH =====
version=2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297 (Thu Nov 8 23:00:07 2018 +0100) on "macos_x64"
si_signo=Segmentation fault: 11(11), si_code=1, si_addr=0x1000
Aborting re-entrant request for stack trace.
/Users/imac/flutter/bin/flutter: line 177:   788 Abort trap: 6           "$DART" $FLUTTER_TOOL_ARGS "$SNAPSHOT_PATH" "$@"***

Very grateful for all your help. Please advise, what might be wrong? What might be needed to run Flutter on my iMac?

**THANKS!!!**

Answer (score 0):

I thought that maybe using an older version of the Flutter SDK might be easier on my very old iMac...

so I searched on the Flutter SDK Archive (https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/sdk/archive?tab=macos) for the oldest available SDK release version, and thus downloaded and unzipped the **build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01**...

although I encountered some messages indicating that I should better upgrade my SDK (which I'm NOT planning to do), this time flutter does not CRASH, and the flutter doctor is running correctly!